# Framing on top of brick halfwall

Tags: walls, framing

I have this wall that I'm wanting to make into a flat wall. I plan to use furring strips with rigid foam insulation on the bottom brick half. Then another wall of 2x4 studs in front of the existing ones, notching them for the PEX, etc.
My question is, how do I go about setting this second wall on the ledge to make it flush? Do I align the bottom plate (which will be sitting on the existing ledge) outwards into the room to account for the foam board that will be on the brick face? 
Has anyone done something like this? I'm open to new ideas as well, just been building a bathroom to fit the existing layout.[image]

Comment: How thick will it be after foam and furring strips? You could then compensate for that with 2x6 for your bottom plate then build your 2x4 wall up from there. I can imagine a 2x4 bottom plate half way on the wall....

Comment: the lower half of the wall will extend about 3/4" from the existing bottom plate  The existing studs are already 3.5" back from the edge, elsewhere in the finished part of the basement the builders used a 2x6 on the ledge, but didn't bring out the upper half of the wall. So it's basically a ledge all around the exterior walls. Just wondering if there's a right or wrong way to do this

Comment: The idea of using a 2x6 for the the flat plate on top of the ledge is that you end up having a good width on the ledge to be able to secure it to the bricks, whether that be some type of fasteners or construction adhesive. With the 2x6 you can easily overhang without worry of it tipping. If it turns out that the 5 1/2 inch total width if the 2x6 is too much you can rip it down to somewhat narrower,

Answer (score 1):

If it was me I would use 2x2 steel stud in front of the brick ( assuming that gives enough room for required r value). Wood that thin doesn't really hold shape very well it tends to curve and banana. A disadvantage of 2x2 steel would be that it isn't very strong if you need to hang anything off of the wall. If you did need to hang something like a TV then you could frame in a section of three-quarter inch plywood.

In terms of running your pipes ensure that they are on the house side of the insulation. Do not bury water pipes in insulation if your region experiences freezing temperatures.

With this method you have one continuous plumb and flat wall from floor to ceiling. Then you are free to do whatever you want to do in behind it. I would add some ties to aid with lateral movement.

Comment: So you would run the 2x2s from floor to ceiling in front of brick?

Comment: Yes and in between the studs you can add your insulation.